# Definition of Extensionality: why no biconditional?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm confused about the definition of extensionality.

In the textbook I use ([Set Theory: An Open Introduction](https://st.openlogicproject.org/settheory-screen.pdf), page 108):

> For any sets $A$ and $B$: $\forall x (x \in A \leftrightarrow x \in B) \rightarrow (A = B)$.

Also on wikipedia (except the "for any sets $A$ and $B$" is also formalized and $X$ is a set):

> $\forall A \forall B (\forall X(X \in A \leftrightarrow X \in B) \rightarrow A = B)$

**My question:** Why is it just a conditional and not a biconditional? Why isn't it $(A = B) \leftrightarrow \forall x(x \in A \leftrightarrow x \in B)$? The naive definition on page 14 states it as a biconditional as well:

> If $A$ and $B$ are sets, then $A = B$ **iff** every member of $A$ is also a member of $B$, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

The other direction is part of the definition of $=$, and therefore not necessary as part of the set theory axioms. Basically, $=$ is defined as $A=B$ meaning that for any formula $\varphi$, we have $\varphi(A)$ iff $\varphi(B)$. Containing a fixed element $x$ is one example of such a formula.

Comment: So while it wouldn't be wrong to define it with $\leftrightarrow$, just $\rightarrow$ is already enough, did I understand that correctly? Would then $A = B \rightarrow \forall x (x \in A \leftrightarrow x \in B)$ be a correct definition as well?

Comment: @LinusDieLinse Your first part is correct. The standard phrasing of the axiom is just trimmed down to avoid redundancy. But your formula isn't right. Your formula is the converse of the axiom of extensionality, it is a consequence of the definition of equality, and it opens up the possibility that sets with the same elements might be unequal. Which is not what we want.